# Why pdfcsplain format breaks with \frlang?

Tags: csplain, enctex

Outlook and copy/paste of `pdfcsplain` run on the following file works well:

```
\input utf8lat1 \input lmfonts
ê é à
\end
```

Outlook and copy/paste of `pdfcsplain` run on the following file is broken:

```
\input utf8lat1 \input t1code \frlang \input lmfonts
ê é à
\end
```

Why?

(*NOTE: recent csplain is used (Mar2019) where `\frlang` is enabled by default*)

*BTW: What means `\oripdfoutput` in `csplain.ini`? And why `\xprncodes=0` is used in `csenc-u.tex` but `\xprncode`s are enabled in `csplain.ini`?*

Comment: `\xprncode` has no effect when `\mubytelog` is equal to `1`, so `\xprncodes=0` in `csenc-u.tex` is redundant. As for `\oripdfoutput`, it seems it may have some application in document which uses `csplain` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\input t1code` must be before `\input utf8lat1` because `t1code` does very basic settings, another macros (used in utf8lat1) depend on such settings. If you use `\input t1code` in csplain then this `\input` is recommended as very first `\input` in your document:

```
\input t1code \input utf8lat1 \frlang \input lmfonts
ê é à
\end
```

Note that this "obscurity" is here only when csplain is used in 8-bit TeX (like pdfTeX). If csplain is used in luaTeX or XeTeX then `\input t1code` nor `\input utf8lat1` must be never used:

```
\frlang \input lmfonts
ê é à
\end
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue can be reproduced without `\frlang`: it's `t1code` together with `lmfonts`.

The problem is that `\cmaccents` remains in force. Fix it by issuing `\csaccents`:

```
\input utf8lat1
\input t1code
\frlang
\input lmfonts
\csaccents

ê é à

\end
```

[image]